# How to reconnect my router to the internet without physically resetting it?

Tags: router, internet

At my building, the internet connection becomes unlimited if I connect after midnight. But as I use a router, it's always connected and I'm not figuring out a way to tell it to disconnect and then connect again. My objective is to make a program to automatically restart the router after midnight to power-up my downloads.

The usual approach I use is to physically turn it off and then on again.

Is there a way I can accomplish that?

**EDIT**

It's a D-Link DI-524 wiress router

Comment: what sort of router?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, you can use [WinRouter Restarter](http://harisoft.net.tf/index_files/Page597.htm). This utility will restart your router at a user specified time, start downloading and also shutdown your PC at a user specified time.

> - Restart the Router before free downloading hours
> - Shutdown your PC after free downloading hours
> - Automatically starts your PC, Restarts Router, starts download and
>     shutdown your PC
> - No Need to setup Windows Scheduler, it itself has an inbuilt
>     Scheduler, just configure it by selecting which downloading programs
>     to run
> - No need to install Telnet Software, has inbuilt support
> - Nice User Interface
> - Low Resource Usage
> - And Best of All, it's Free!

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work. I tried to configurate it as much as I can but didn't get it to work